# Spring boot's XADataSourceAutoConfiguration vs AtomikosJtaConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, jta, xa, atomikos

I am trying to understand how the `XADataSourceAutoConfiguration` relates to the `AtomikosJtaConfiguration` and more generally the `**JtaConfiguration`.

More specifically how the two classes below relate to each other:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.AtomikosJtaConfiguration
```

I need a spring boot spring batch application to participate in transactions involving two databases.

Can someone please tell me how the two classes relate to each other?

I was not able to find much documentation in the javadocs API or in the reference documentation about **`XADataSourceAutoConfiguration`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XADataSourceAutoConfiguration` is responsible for taking an `XADataSource` and applying a transaction manager-specific wrapper. That wrapper is how the data source is enlisted in any XA transactions.

`AtomikosJtaConfiguration` is responsible for configuring Atomikos, including providing the Atomikos-specific `XADataSource` wrapper that will ensure that Atomikos knows about the `XADataSource` and enlists it in any XA transactions.

Comment: I also come across XADataSourceAutoConfiguration and XADataSource classes and trying to understand XA transactions in detail.I could not find any spring related documentation regarding how spring implements XA transactions. A detailed resource would be more helpful.

Comment: Spring does not implement XA transactions. It's Atomikos (as the transaction manager) and the database vendor (as a participant in the transaction) that do so.